# How to use swift to write This

Tags: ios, image

I want to change some OC code to swift,but there has some question,i need help

```
CGFloat imageWidth = 200;
CGFloat imageHeight = 200; 
// 遍历像素
int pixelNum = imageWidth * imageHeight;
uint32_t* pCurPtr = (uint32_t*)malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight);
for (int i = 0; i < pixelNum; i++, pCurPtr++){
    //at here i don't kown how to change, can you help me
    //**************************
    if ((*pCurPtr & 0xFFFFFF00) < 0x99999900)    // 将白色变成透明
    {
        // 改成下面的代码，会将图片转成想要的颜色
        uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)pCurPtr;
        ptr[3] = red; //0~255
        ptr[2] = green;
        ptr[1] = blue;
    }
    //**************************

}
```

Comment: you should do it with yourself.just read some basic syntax about swift and you can easily write this.

Answer (score 0):

var imageWidth: CGFloat = 200

var imageHeight: CGFloat = 200

var pixelNum = imageWidth * imageHeight

var pCurPtr = (malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight) as! uint32_t)

var i = 0

while i < pixelNum {

```
if (pCurPtr & 0xFFFFFF00) < 0x99999900 {


    var ptr: UInt8 = UInt8(pCurPtr)

    ptr[3] = red
    //0~255
    ptr[2] = green
    ptr[1] = blue
}

i += 1, pCurPtr += 1
```

}